# Issue with CSS 'everything except last' selector

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have a list of sub-lists. Each sublist has its own children. I need to apply style to all except the last sub-list. I use:

```
.list:not(:last-child) > .sublist {
  color: red;
}
```

But it is applying for all the sublists. Here's a demonstrating code (fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8m72m53r/3/):

```css
:not(:last-child) > .row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="box">
  <li class="row">One</li>
  <li class="row">Two</li>
  <li class="row">Three</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="box">
  <li class="row">FOur</li>
  <li class="row">Five</li>
  <li class="row">Six</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="box">
  <li class="row">Seven</li>
  <li class="row">Eight</li>
  <li class="row">Nine</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/yfs8L2a5/) - you pretty much had it, just make sure to use the [:last-of-type pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)

```css
.box:not(:last-of-type) > .row {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="box">
    <li class="row">One</li>
    <li class="row">Two</li>
    <li class="row">Three</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="box">
    <li class="row">FOur</li>
    <li class="row">Five</li>
    <li class="row">Six</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="box">
    <li class="row">Seven</li>
    <li class="row">Eight</li>
    <li class="row">Nine</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help you:

```
.box>.row:not(:last-of-type)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are looking for this. But if you want to style all items but the last ones, use something like this:

```
.row:not(:last-child) {
    color: red;
}
```